# Adding metadata or tags on S3 Upload with FormData

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, form-data

I'm uploading a file to S3 and I'd like to attach some metadata/tags to it, but unfortunately I'm unable to do so it seems with my current method.

I'm creating a `FormData` object in Javascript and appending a couple of tags that I read through the S3 documentation are required in order to attach metadata with the file.

Here is the file info (which gets uploading fine, already):

```
fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', presignedRes.data.fields.AWSAccessKeyId);
fd.append('key', presignedRes.data.fields.key);
fd.append('policy', presignedRes.data.fields.policy);
fd.append('signature', presignedRes.data.fields.signature);
fd.append('acl', 'bucket-owner-full-control');
fd.append('file', parsedFile);
```

And below is the metadata I'm attempting to attach. I'd like to have it be JSON if possible.

```
fd.append('x-amz-meta-tag', JSON.stringify([{'name': 'email'}]));
```

Unfortunately when the upload submits to S3 successfully, it fails to pass through this metadata above.

I'd like to do this if possible without having to use the aws node library.

Comment: There are about 3 problems here.  You should get an error back, unless you are also adding rules for any `x-amz-meta-*` keys to the policy before generating the signature, but your description sounds like it silently succeeds and has no effect.  Next, `file` must be the last form field added.  If you are adding more things after the file, then this should also cause an error, but it might be silently ignored if the file is larger than about ~20K, the size of the buffer S3 uses for everything that isn't the file...

Comment: ...and for tagging, you want `x-amz-tagging`.  The key/value pairs must be urlencoded `foo=bar&baz=buzz%20fizz`, not JSON.  Not sure which is the cause of your issue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've been trying to get this work for so long, and finally with your help I was able to! If you'd like to respond with this in an answer I'll gladly accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Which of these things was the issue?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot moving the positioning of the metadata tag to before the file in the FormData object.